# Live streaming in laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to implement live streaming in laravel..

I tried 'kandy-laravel package' (https://github.com/Kandy-IO/kandy-laravel/tree/master ). But this is not worked. On 'php artisan vendor:publish' nothing is happen..

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html" : "~5.0",
    "toddish/verify": "~5",
    "kandy-io/kandy-laravel": "2.5.0"
},
```

And then update composer

```
composer update
```

For publish

```
php artisan vendor:publish --force --provider=Kodeplus\Kandylaravel\KandylaravelServiceProvider --tag=public
```

On executing above command show this message

> Nothing to publish for tag [public]

Please give me some suggestions and tutorials. Thanks

Comment: Any reason for downvote??  so I improve my question

Comment: SO is not a place to request for tutorials. The composer.json feels directly copied from the repo readme and it feels like you do not have basic knowledge of managing packages using composer.

Comment: "I would like to implement live streaming" isn't really specific. You will atleast not to clarify what you mean by live straming. Just streaming videos or actually someone broadcasting live. What tools you want to use to broadcast?

Comment: Sorry.. I just want to do live broadcasting using webcam..

Answer (score 0):

Please follow `Package Setup` section of `Readme.md`

[kodeplusdev/kandy-laravel GitHub link on the #Package Setup](https://github.com/kodeplusdev/kandy-laravel#package-setup)

---

Follow steps

1. Install package `composer require kandy-io/kandy-laravel`
2. Publish *public* files : `php artisan vendor:publish --force --provider=Kodeplus\Kandylaravel\KandylaravelServiceProvider --tag=public`
3. Publish *migrations* files : `php artisan vendor:publish --force --provider=Kodeplus\Kandylaravel\KandylaravelServiceProvider --tag=migrations`
4. Publish *config* file : `php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Kodeplus\Kandylaravel\KandylaravelServiceProvider --tag=config`
5. Run migration `php artisan migrate`
6. Seed database `php artisan db:seed`
7. Insert your kandy.io credentials